# Trying to hide Div element with css display:none; doesn't hide it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JS code that creates the div (I created it with JS and not HTML for education purposes):

```
    var profile = document.createElement('div');
    .... some code...
    document.body.appendChild(profile);
```

Now in my css file that is associated with the main html file, I have this:

```
.profile{
    display: none;
}
```

This does not hide the profile div, and I do not understand why.
I assume I am missing something in the CSS file, but after looking in the internet I did not find an answer.

Comment: profile is not class name it is variable

Comment: You need to target the `<div>` you created and apply the styling to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your JS code:

```
var profile = document.createElement('div');
profile.className = 'profile';
```

Now the css can be applied to this element since it has a class called 'profile'

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your `<div>` does not have the class 'profile'

Have a look at this [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/tonopowoku/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: Thanks, I did not mark as the main response but I appreciate it and it helped me!

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be next:

After this line `var profile = document.createElement('div');`
add a className selector to an element by this
`profile.className = "your class name here";`

Then in CSS use this:

```
.your class name here{
    display: none;
}
```